# Point Nginx reverse proxy to virtual host on different VM

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, nginx, web-server, virtualhost

I have 1 VM running Nginx to distribute incoming requests for different domains (subdomains)on the same IP to different Virtual machines.

my Nginx config file for one example is very basic for now.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name cloud.something.xyz;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.77;
  }
}
```

This is pointing to the correct VM but it shows the default apache page on that VM instead of the desired virtual host (cloud.something.xyz).

If I forward ports to http://192.168.1.77 directly, then the subdomains / enabled sites work as expected, so I think my Apache config is fine and the problem is on the Nginx config side.

`proxy_pass http://192.168.1.77/folderloacation` and similar tries just give me configuration errors and other mysterious results

What am I missing to make the proxy use the correct virtual host instead of directing to the other VMs default page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more aware of the Apach Based Proxy Config, but what you are missing is the preservation of the HTTP Host Header.

In your setup, the Host Header does not get sent over to your configured Proxy.

Wou have to preserve it with the module called http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header

The appropriate answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834025/how-to-preserve-request-url-with-nginx-proxy-pass